# No building file; No LaTeX=>PDF

Tags: installing, compiling, miktex, texniccenter

I installed MiKTeX 2.8 and TeXnicCenter on a friend's PC.
There seems to be a quite weird issue.
There seems to be missing the option "LaTeX=>PDF".
Clicking on the arrow to select the output file (e.g. DVI, PDF etc.) nothing appears.
That's the 1st issue.

The 2nd one, probably connected to the 1st, occurs while trying to build the file.
Clicking the relevant icon, nothing happens!

The package `texpdf` is installed on her PC as well.
I cannot remember if I needed to add something, when I installed my LaTeX.

Comment: Check the "Build / Define Output Profiles" menu. There will be a wizard button at the bottom of that dialog. Use it to find your latex executables and define the default profiles. Shouldn't be any reason to modify the path.

Comment: did you installed MiKTeX first, then TC oder the other way round?

Comment: Did you try with a small hello-World-example which uses a standard class like article?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but, I had a similar problem with WinEdit 5.5.  The way I resolved it was by uninstalling and reinstalling WinEdit.  BTW - Have you tried compiling with TeXWorks?  This will probably indicate whether the problem lies with MiKTeX or TeXNiC.

Comment: @Herbert I installed MikTeX fisrt and TeXNiC Center afterwards...hmmm...Do you think I should try all the way around...?I'll give it a shot!!!

at Fischer I tried a simple text like 5 sentences in a standard class like article...

I know how to use LaTeX, however I cannot figure out what went wrong...

Comment: @Thanos: no, that is the correct order. When TeXNicCenter is startet first it looks for the MiKTeX directory and you'll have to have to accept the settings before you can use TC. Did you had such a menu on the frist start of TC?

Comment: @Thanos: what I meant is: did you try with a document where miktex has to install packages on-the-fly or with a document for which all files exist in your system? The broken on-the-fly-install is a common problem with texniccenter (but rereading your question I guess you have a different problem).

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined your profiles yet.  As stated by Mike Renfro, you can use the TeXnicCenter wizard to guide you through this process.  Essentially you need to tell TeXnicCenter where to look for the MiKTeX executables.

On any of my Windows machines, I have MiKTeX saved to [`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9`].  However, the executables you need are buried further (for 32-bit) [`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin`] and (for 64-bit) [`C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`].  Below I'll list which executable should be pointed to for each default profile.  Note: Your path may be different from mine if you are not using a Windows 7 machine, not using a 64-bit version of MiKTeX, version 2.9 of MiKTeX, or deviated from a default install.  However the principles remain the same.

"Path to (La)TeX complier"

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe
```

"Path to BibTeX executable"

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\bibtex.exe
```

"Path to MakeIndex executable"

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\makeindex.exe
```

For Viewers, this will completely depend on your personal preference.

The default Viewer for DVI is:

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES\MIKTEX 2.9\MIKTEX\BIN\X64\YAP.EXE
```

For PDF, I link to my Adobe Acrobat executable.

For PS, a default GSWin install links me to

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.04\bin\gswin64.exe
```

Hope this helps.